# Create a list of lists from a one-dimensional list, grouping each element by length

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Let's say that I have a flat list:

```
flat_list = ["one", "a", "two", "b", "ab"]
```

My goal is to get a list of lists, each one containing every element with the same length, something like this:

```
list_lists = [["one", "two"], ["a", "b"], ["ab"]]
```

Is it possible to accomplish this with a simple list comprehension?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You might want to re-read the question.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 is right, this is a different question entirely, even I thought it was the duplicate question at first

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I had seen the other topic, the problem was a little different tho

Comment: @RoadRunner, in the OP's defense, with `itertools` it isn't a wacky one-liner at all, it's rather intuitive IMO

Comment: @RoadRunner and how would a dictionary make it simpler than a list-comprehension?

Comment: the question marked as a duplicate is not the same as this one

Comment: here's an answer, but it won't let me submit  `[[el for el in flat_list if len(el) == target_size] for target_size in range(len(flat_list))]`

Comment: @ᴬᴶᵁᴾᴾᴬᴸ `d = defaultdict(list)
for lst in flat_list:
    key = len(lst)
    d[key].append(lst)`? grouping with dicts is always very straightforward.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ This one asks to group them by their elements' lengths. I've updated the example to make it clearer.

Comment: @ayhan Never mind, misunderstood the problem. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`itertools.groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to accomplish this (first we sort the list by length, using `sorted`, so that `groupby` works the way we want it to):

```
[list(group) for key, group in groupby(sorted(flat_list, key=len, reverse=True), len)]
```

---

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> flat_list = ["one", "two", "a", "b", "ab"]
>>> list_of_lists = [list(group) for key, group in groupby(sorted(flat_list, key=len, reverse=True), len)]
>>> 
>>> list_of_lists
[['one', 'two'], ['ab'], ['a', 'b']]
>>>
```

Comment: As the many, many questions which this is a duplicate of explain, `groupby` works with _contiguous_ groups.  The only reason your code appears to work is the order of `flat_list`.  If you used the current order in the question, you'd see `[['one'], ['a'], ['two'], ['b'], ['ab']]` instead.  If you want to use groupby, you'll need to sort the list by your keyfunc first.  (Aside: `lambda x: len(x)` is better written `len`.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my cut:

```
[[el for el in flat_list if len(el) == target_size + 1] for target_size in range(max([len(el) for el in flat_list]))]
```

Though I would prefer to split it into two lines:

```
max_len = max([len(el) for el in flat_list])
[[el for el in flat_list if len(el) == target_size + 1] for target_size in range(max_len )]
```

This will actually produce an empty list for any sizes lacking elements, so an input of `flat_list = ["one", "two", "a", "b", "ab", 'eleven']` will produce

```
[['a', 'b'], ['ab'], ['one', 'two'], [], [], ['eleven']]
```

Answer (score 0):

another "pure python"

```
flat_list = ["one", "two", "a", "b", "ab"]

d = {}
for w in flat_list:
    d.update({len(w): d.setdefault(len(w), []) + [w]})
list(d.values())

Out[99]: [['one', 'two'], ['a', 'b'], ['ab']]
```

can be rewrtten as a list comp with some fancy footwork, still need an empty dict to start

```
d = {}
[list(d.values())
 for w in flat_list + [''] if w == ''
                              or d.update({len(w): d.setdefault(len(w), []) + [w]})]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3(will work with python 2 also) implementation without importing any libraries. Simple 4 liner

```
flat_list = ["one", "a", "two", "b", "ab"]

tmp_dict = dict()
for i in flat_list:
    tmp_dict.setdefault(len(i), []).append(i)

list(tmp_dict.values()

Out[1]: [['one', 'two'], ['a', 'b'], ['ab']]
```